# moment.format() in nodejs is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I'm using momentjs in both angular code and a utility application written in nodejs. There's a utility function in angular as follows:

```
function _fromMomentPeriod(period) {
    return { 
        start: period.start ? period.start.format() : undefined,  // keep the tz info. Do not convert to utc
        end:   period.end ? period.end.format() : undefined,  // keep the tz info. Do not convert to utc
    };
}
```

Needless to say, period.start and period.end are moment objects. This runs fine in the browser, but in node, I get 'format is not a function'. When I inspect the period.start object, it is a moment object but I do not see a format function on it. It looks like this:

```
{
    "_isAMomentObject": true,
    "_isUTC": false,
    "_locale": {
        "_ordinalParse": {},
        "_abbr": "en",
        "_ordinalParseLenient": {}
    },
    "_d": "2015-12-23T14:48:37.383Z"
}
```

I'm new to node so I presume I'm missing something obvious. What is it?

Comment: The reason you don't see the format function is because the functions are part of the prototype of your moment object.

Comment: Try `console.log(Object.keys(period.start.__proto__))`

Comment: @see-sharper How do you initialize variable `period`?

Comment: @Quy: I wondered about that - I'm inspecting in Visual Studio Code which is not as helpful as the Chrome debugger. But that does not explain why I get 'format not a function'.

Comment: @stdob: it's converted to a moment in another function like this: period.start = moment(period.start). Initially it's a string.

Comment: I used lodash's .functions method to print out all the functions on the object and its prototype. Nothing.

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out. I was using lodash's cloneDeep function, assuming it would do the same job as angular.copy. It turns out it doesn't copy object prototype properties.